# MutableLiveList class for android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have wrote a `MutableLiveList` class for android, similar to existing `MutableLiveData`, but this class instead handles a list and notifies its observers on structural changes like adding items and removing items. It is intended to be used inside viewModels similar to `MutableLiveData`. Class implementation is like this:

```
class MutableLiveList<E> : MutableList<E> {

    private val list = mutableListOf<E>()
    private val listChange = MutableLiveData<Triple<Int, Int, ListEvent>>()

    fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: ListObserver) {
        //newly added observer must not listen to old changeEvents
/*EDIT*/listChange.value = Triple(-1, 0, NONE)

        listChange.observe(owner, {
            when (it.third) {
/*EDIT*/        NONE -> {}
                ADD -> observer.onAdded(it.first, it.second)
                REMOVE -> observer.onRemoved(it.first, it.second)
            }
        })
    }

    //List methods : delegate to corresponding list.methods
    override val size get() = list.size
    override fun contains(element: E) = list.contains(element)
    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<E>) = list.containsAll(elements)
    override fun get(index: Int) = list[index]
    override fun indexOf(element: E) = list.indexOf(element)
    override fun lastIndexOf(element: E) = list.lastIndexOf(element)
    override fun isEmpty() = list.isEmpty()
    override fun iterator() = list.iterator()
    override fun listIterator() = list.listIterator()
    override fun listIterator(index: Int) = list.listIterator(index)
    override fun subList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) = list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)

    //MutableList methods : trigger list observers.
    override fun add(element: E) = add(size, element).run { true }
    override fun add(index: Int, element: E) = list.add(index, element).also {
        listChange.value = Triple(index, 1, ADD)
    }

    override fun addAll(elements: Collection<E>) = addAll(size, elements)
    override fun addAll(index: Int, elements: Collection<E>) = list.addAll(index, elements).also {
        listChange.value = Triple(index, elements.size, ADD)
    }

    override fun clear() {
        val size = size
        list.clear()
        listChange.value = Triple(0, size, REMOVE)
    }

    override fun remove(element: E): Boolean {
        val index = list.indexOf(element)
        if (index == -1)
            return false
        removeAt(index)
        return true
    }

    override fun removeAt(index: Int) = list.removeAt(index).also {
        listChange.value = Triple(index, 1, REMOVE)
    }

    override fun retainAll(elements: Collection<E>): Boolean {
        var modified = false
        for (ele in list.toList()) {
            if (ele !in elements) {
                remove(ele)
                modified = true
            }
        }
        return modified
    }

    override fun removeAll(elements: Collection<E>): Boolean {
        var modified = false
        for (ele in list.toList()) {
            if (ele in elements) {
                remove(ele)
                modified = true
            }
        }
        return modified
    }

    override fun set(index: Int, element: E) = list.set(index, element).also {
        listChange.value = Triple(index, 1, REMOVE)
        listChange.value = Triple(index, 1, ADD)
    }
}

interface ListObserver {
    fun onAdded(start: Int, size: Int)
    fun onRemoved(start: Int, size: Int)
}

private enum class ListEvent {
    NONE, ADD, REMOVE;
}
```

Example usage:

```
val userList = MutableLiveList<User>()
.
.
.
userListAdapter = UserListAdapter(userList)
userList.observe(this, object : ListObserver {
    override fun onAdded(start: Int, size: Int) {
        userListAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(start, size)
    }

    override fun onRemoved(start: Int, size: Int) {
        userListAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(start, size)
    }
})
```

This is working fine for now in main thread. I suspect would this work on background thread or not! Is this good enough?  Are there any lurking bugs?

**EDIT**: Added two lines in the code. I don't know if these two lines are necessarily required (I tried with and without, both worked well). Without this line, whenever a new observer is added, it will get a redundant `onAdded`/`onRemoved` event depending on the recent change made to the list, before attaching the observer.

Comment: @Tenfour04 huh.. kindof. I don't know how to write unit tests. Actually I doubt something in this code, which I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67255037/is-there-any-guarenteed-way-to-mimic-some-action-between-ondestroy-and-oncr). If possible answer that please.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed which Exchange site we’re on because I’m using the app. Nothing wrong with what you’re asking here.

Answer (score 2):

You could define the class constructor this way to avoid manually delegating those basic functions:

```
class MutableLiveList<E> private constructor(private val list: MutableList<E>) : MutableList<E> by list {
    constructor(): this(mutableListOf())

    //...
}
```

If you want to be able to modify the list from a background thread, you should use `postValue` instead of `setValue` on the MutableLiveData.

You might consider designing this to be observed using a LifecycleCoroutineScope instead of a LifecycleOwner. Then you can back it with a MutableFlow and eliminate the `NONE` case. Your observe function could use `launchWhenStarted` and collect the flow to the passed listener.

One possible gotcha I see is if `retainAll` or `removeAll` is used on this List, it will fire the observer for each individual item removed. Not just with the class functions, but also the inline extension function overloads that take a lambda. But maybe that's the design intent.

Since your `removeAll` and `retainAll` rely on `remove`, they run in *O(m*n^2)* time. You might want to remove directly using the iterator so you can avoid copying the list and searching for each removed element.

Comment: Thank you for that interface delegation suggestion. But I didn't quite get that paragraphs about `removeAll` and `retainAll`. Mainly that thing about avoiding copying the list. Btw, I know implementation of those two function will have worst performance. But since those removed elements are not continuous, I have to fire observer for individual elements. Otherwise I have to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: `toList()` copies the list into another list. Then each `in` call searches the list. Then each `remove` call indirectly uses `indexOf`, so you have *O(m\*n^2)* complexity. If you do something like `override fun removeAll(elements: Collection<E>) = list.removeAll { it in elements }`, then it will only be *O(m\*n)* complexity and no list copy is required.

Comment: I don't know how `removeAll(predicate:..)` is implemented. But here, for every being removed, observer should be fired. Does that happen when using `removeAll`?

Comment: Oh, good point. It won't trigger the observer for everything because it directly sets values. You would have to write your own implementation if you want to improve efficiency

Comment: Can you write something better with the requirement that it should trigger observers?

Comment: You can pretty much copy the code from the standard library for `retainAll`/`removeAll` which both use a private function `filterInPlace`. You just need to be sure that you trigger the observer correctly when removing and adding items. Also, you might want to add `removeAll(predicate)` and `retainAll(predicate)` as members of your class to prevent the standard library extension functions from accidentally being used since they will trigger your observers incorrectly.